# app crashed while trim audio in react native error - video:0kB audio:476kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg, trim, react.js

I'm trying to trim audio file,  don't get any error but app is crashed.
Last line of process is

video:0kB audio:476kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:

Please help

Comment: And what app might that be? Because ffmpeg isn’t a React Native app. It’s a command-line application.

Comment: Need to see all of the lines from the process and the ffmpeg command that was being executed.

Comment: I have used this command '-y -i inputeAudio.acc -ss 10 -t 30000 -acodec copy AudioTrim.mp3'

Comment: @PreetiSolanki Need to see the complete log from the command.